# asp.net mvc4 signout link route not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using asp.net mvc4. I can't hit ~/Account/LogOff from my app.  The default route should catch it and route it to the appropriate controller.  in routeconfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Shouldn't that catch the url?

Code for the link creation

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Signout", "LogOff", "Account" , new{controller = "Account"
 , action = "LogOff"}, new{ target = "_self"})
```

For some reason that is driving me crazy, I can't hit

```
//
    // POST: /Account/LogOff

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        fam.SignOut(false);
        SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequest = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);
        return new RedirectResult(signOutRequest.WriteQueryString());

    }
```

I've tried adding a route before and after the "Home" maproute. Neither one seems to work. What in the world am I missing here? I've written dozens of asp.net mvc apps and have not had this problem. It's blowing my mind. Please help.

Cheers,
~ck

Comment: looks perfect. my guess is the route and link gets matched right but the method not. cant point to any clear *reason* for it. I would start by removing the antiforgerytoken. no one will suffer if a user fakes the logout

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you have a `[HttpPost]`. What it basically means is that it fetches request coming from a submit button from forms but since your not using a submit button neither a form, your Logoff action will be skipped.

You can resolve this by 2 reasons:

1.) Change the `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`

2.) Just simply direct your link to your action:

`@Html.ActionLink("Signout", "LogOff", "Account")`

Answer (score 0):

Oh I was doing a get via the link click. The method is for post. I wrapped the link in a form tag and on the link click I submit the form as usual. This fixed the problem and im able to hit my controller method.

Comment: Why not just remove [HttpPost] attribute from the action?

Comment: This is the correct method, wrapping a form around the link and posting.  I'm not sure why this is getting a down voted except that the person doesn't understand why MVC 4 ships with LogOff requiring a post.  That reason is due to AntiForgeryToken which needs to make its way back to the server to prevent malicious sites, etc, logging users off by direct linking to the LogOff action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `[HttpPost]` attribute from the `LogOff()` action. `@Html.ActionLink()` will create a regular link (`<a>` tag), so clicking on it will issue a GET request.

Comment: I cannot down vote but this is incorrect.  The post is required for AntiForgeryToken